# Which continuity does the 2015 Amazing Spider-Man comic take part in?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

I got the #1 issue of a comic magazine called "The Amazing Spider-Man". The publication date is December(!) 2015.

This comes after the previous "Amazing Spider-Man" stopped, as most Marvel comics did, for the big event called "Secret Wars".

As far as I can tell, the story continues from the last "volume",

> where Peter has his own company.

Given the above, it would seem it's Earth-616. However that Earth is supposed to have been destroyed during SW.

At the same time, Nick Fury appears in the comic and he looks like Samuel Jackson, who is the Nick Fury of the Cinematic and Ultimate universes -and that's a discrepancy with Earth-616, whose Nick Fury doesn't look anything like that.

My best guess would be that after the end of Secret Wars (which hasn't been published yet) the universes get restored (or at least some of them do), but with some elements changed, one of which could be Fury.

Is there any *official* word about which universe the new Amazing Spider-Man takes part in?

Comment: Re: Nick Fury, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_Fury,_Jr.  Nick Fury, Jr. was active in 616 for a while before *Secret Wars*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Spider-man series takes place in the new post-*Secret Wars* Marvel universe, which seems to be separate and distinct from the familiar Earth-616.

In [the *Secret Wars* kickoff event in January](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7L6mDjQHNs) Tom Brevoort, Marvel's Executive Editor, and Axel Alonso, the Editor-in-Chief, talked about the fate of the Marvel universe:

Transcript of some interesting things:

- **Earth-616 and Earth-1610 (the Ultimates Universe) are going to merge**:

  > **Alonso:** The Ultimate universe, the Marvel universe, they're going to smash together. Imagine it was two pizzas: they're going to slap together, you can have all-new toppings, some toppings are going to drop off, you're going to yell about some that are missing, you're going to love the new ones that are there, and that is the Marvel Universe moving forward.
- **Neither is going to survive**

  > **Brevoort:** The actual main event is going to happen in *Secret Wars* 1. So, the Ultimate universe and the Marvel universe will collide, and the heroes of those two worlds will have eight hours to figure out what to do about it before both universes are destroyed. And they won't.
- **What comes out the other side is going to be something between the two**

  > **Brevoort:** *Battleworld* essentially is the detritus that's left over after the destruction of the Marvel universe and the Ultimate universe, and it is the little melting pot in which the new Marvel universe will be created, will be fermented, in which all the little bits and pieces, the dribs and drabs, all the little sections of Earths that were within those incursion zones, those areas that were intersected, all those little pieces have remained, and they will be fused into a single, gigantic organism that is *Battleworld*, in which various characters will live their lives and contend with this new situation, and will set up all of the building blocks and all of the bedrock of what the new Marvel universe will be from that point going forward.

[A June interview with Jason Latour](http://ca.ign.com/articles/2015/06/23/spider-gwen-will-make-her-video-game-debut-this-fall), writer of the *Spider-Gwen* series, suggests that they're still going to be calling the new universe "616", at least in discussion with fans:

> **IGN Comics: Now that we know we’re getting another Spider-Gwen series, the big question is, will she be a part of the “main” Marvel Universe after Secret Wars, or if she’ll still be in her alternate universe on Earth-65?**
>
> **Jason Latour:** The answer is “yes”. No seriously, it’s a little of column A and a little of column B.
>
> *[...]*
>
> [B]ouncing over to the 616 now and then is something we’re eager to explore too.

But Latour doesn't speak for Marvel as a company, so it's not yet clear how official we should consider that statement.

Answer (score 1):

Marvel's main universe is the "616" universe, after whatever cosmic weirdness resolved Secret Wars.  You can see this most easily in the references to Horizon Labs, the "Superior Spider-Man" era, and in the presence of Miguel O'Hara--all of which are recent events from the pre-Secret Wars 616.

Oh, and that Nick Fury is the illegitimate son of the Howling Commando--also a 616 era development.

Comment: I didn't know there was a "new" Fury in 616. As he was the only thing that seemed out of place, it makes sense that it's still 616, or at least its continuation.